# How to make a cors proxy server process https request with http basic authentication?

Tags: javascript, https, proxy, cors

I've been using a CORS-Proxy for http requests, which is just fine for me. Recently I came across an API for sending emails (by https requests), that requires http basic authentication. I am wondering how to implement this.

this is the proxy server i use:
https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy

and considering this
https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere
this one support https but no basic authentication.

Comment: CORS Anywhere does support Basic authorization, see https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/pull/8#issuecomment-52154338 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials)? This should work for you imho:

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://bar.other/resources/credentialed-content/';

function callOtherDomain(){
  if(invocation) {
    invocation.open('GET', url, true);
    invocation.withCredentials = true;
    invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
    invocation.send(); 
  }
```

Or you could also add the necessary request header on every request (but this shouldn't be necessary imho):

```
invocation.setRequestHeader('Authorization', btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(username + ":" + password))));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it seems i didn't make myself clear. what i need is basiclly a proxy server which can process http plus https request. Best part is, it is for node js. with which, i can call any url through the proxy server by adding the address to the server's url,and access the proxy server instead of the orignal website.

Comment: @Newset So you want the credentials for the HTTP basic authentication to be used only by the proxy server? Don't know if that's possible, sry.